# Reading excel cell value in Excel Web Access Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, excel-services

I need to read excel cell value.Excel web access webpart is used to display excel file stored in a SharePoint 2013 document library.I need to use Jquery to read the data of excel file currently displaying in EWA webpart and perform some validation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Excel Services ECMAScript Object model to read cell values.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee819929(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee819929%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

http://blogs.office.com/2009/11/30/introducing-the-javascript-object-model-for-excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010/

You can also check other options available for reading cell values:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms546696(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms546696%28v=office.14%29.aspx)